# How do you use a separate class to determine a result?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

my issue is in my "NumberAnalyzer.java" class, I'm supposed to be able to use the "Number.java" class to determine if a number from the ArrayList is odd (as well as even and perfect later on) but since the "isOdd()" method in "Number.java" doesn't read in an int or other variable itself, I can't find a way to test each number to make "oddCount" in the "countOdds" method of "NumberAnalyzer.java" increase to produce the number of odd numbers in the string from the runner class.

**NumberAnalyzer.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.NextAction;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberAnalyzer
{
private ArrayList<Number> list;

public NumberAnalyzer()
{

}

public NumberAnalyzer(String numbers)
{
    list = new ArrayList<Number>();
    String nums = numbers;
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(nums);
    while(chopper.hasNext()){
        int num = chopper.nextInt();
        list.add(new Number(num));
    }
    chopper.close();
    System.out.println(list);
}

public void setList(String numbers)
{
    list = new ArrayList<Number>();
    String nums = numbers;
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(nums);
    while(chopper.hasNext()){
        int num = chopper.nextInt();
        list.add(new Number(num));
    }
    chopper.close();

}

public int countOdds()
{
  int oddCount=0;
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
      if(Number.isOdd()== true){
          oddCount++;
      }
  }
  return oddCount;
}

public int countEvens()
{
  int evenCount=0;



  return evenCount;
}

public int countPerfects()
{
    int perfectCount=0;



  return perfectCount;
}

public String toString( )
{
    return "";
}
}
```

**Number.java**

```
public class Number
{
private Integer number;

public Number()
{


}

public Number(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

public void setNumber(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

public int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}   

public boolean isOdd()
{
    if(number%2==0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean isPerfect()
{
    int total=0;
    for(int i = 1; i < number; i++){
        if(number%i==0){
            total+= i;
        }
    }


    return (number==total);
}   

public String toString( )
{
    String output = getNumber() + "\n" + getNumber()+ "isOdd == " + isOdd() + "\n" + getNumber()+ "isPerfect==" + isPerfect()+ "\n\n";
    return output;
}
}
```

**runner class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Lab16b
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    NumberAnalyzer test = new NumberAnalyzer("5 12 9 6 1 4 8 6");
    out.println(test);
    out.println("odd count = "+test.countOdds());
    out.println("even count = "+test.countEvens());
    out.println("perfect count = "+test.countPerfects()+"\n\n\n");


    //add more test cases


}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: done... (thinking this is what you were asking about)

Comment: An SSCCE should have only one public class and one file.  It should also compile as-is (not sure if that lot does, but not willing to find out until it is one class).

Comment: There is never a way for it to be a single class, as it associates with 3 completely separate .java files in the folder which I am keeping it in.... and it compiles aside from what my question is

Comment: *"There is never a way for it to be a single class, as it associates with 3 completely separate .java files"*  Never heard of anonymous/inner classes?

Comment: BTW - `import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.NextAction;` is not only an unused import, but would issue compiler warnings if used. `import static java.lang.System.*;`  All classes in `lang` are imported automatically.

Comment: no.... I'm in a high school 2nd year AP CSII class and I've never gotten any instruction on those.... googled it to check

Comment: So now is your time to learn something new (or rather, several things).  Are you excited?  1) 'anonymous/inner classes' in a typical search engine will show the top hit as being at Oracle. 2) Visit it and learn about anonymous/inner classes from the experts.

Comment: Already there... I may have a slight idea.. is it like when you would use `this.pre_defined_method();` by chance?

Comment: Ok, so inner classes contain local classes (like when `this.whatever();` might be used..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
test.countOdds());
```

control goes to NumberAnalyzer.java

```
public int countOdds()
{
  int oddCount=0;
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
      if(Number.isOdd()== true){
          oddCount++;
      }
  }
  return oddCount;
}
```

And here you are calling `Number.isOdd()` method by Class name as a static way but i do not think you can do this way because `isOdd()` is not static.

It is compile time error

**Solution:**

Iterate your list and send value one by one from the list to `isOdd(int val)` method.

Try to make `isOdd()` method static which accept one numeric parameter and will return true or false.

increase your counter based on return type as you do.

Comment: Let me know if your question is different.

Comment: I got it answered by rephrasing the question in a new post and I believe its close to what you did

Comment: I have not seen any modification in question. Please modify question if you are looking for something else or comment in detail so that It will visible what is exact solution you are looking for